# Ideally black plates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, thermal-radiation, blackbody

Let's consider $m$ ideally black, thin, infinite plates. Let $T_i$ be the temperature of the $i$-th plate.

For given $T_1 > T_m$, why is the radiant flux between any two adjacent plates the same i.e. for any $k,l \in \lbrace1,..,m-1\rbrace$
$$J_k = \sigma \left(T_k^4 - T_{k+1}^4\right) = \sigma \left(T_l^4 - T_{l+1}^4\right)= J_l~?$$

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a statement of conservation of energy. Consider an imaginary surface between plates $k$ and $k+1$. The flux through this surface is:

$$
J=\sigma T_k^4-\sigma T_{k+1}^4,
$$

where the second term is negative because the energy flows in the opposite direction. If the system is in a state of equilibrium, then the temperatures are not changing with time, and the energy flux through any such surface must be the same across all such surfaces. If this were not the case, energy would build up at one of the plates, a contradiction. Thus, the expression above is independent of $k$.

It appears that there is the added idealization that there is no energy transmitted to anything away from the plates, only between the plates. This is equivalent to saying that the plates are infinite.

Comment: Why would it be a contradiction? And what if $J_1<J_2<...<J_m$? Would the energy always build up in one of them?

Comment: It would be a contradiction because the system would not be in equilibrium if the energy were building up. Physically, the energy of the plate is stored in thermal energy, so if more energy flows through one imaginary surface than flows out the next one, the plate in between would heat up. If $J_1!=J_2$, then energy builds up at plate $2$ at a rate of $J_2-J_1$.

Comment: And why does it have to be in equilibrium? I'd say it isn't, since $T_1 > T_m$ and we don't know anything about $T_2, ..., T_{m-1}$. And the equilibrium would be if $T_1 = T_2 = ... = T_m$

Comment: Besides, why is it so because of the fact that the plates are thin? What would happen if they weren't?

Comment: The system is in equilibrium as long as nothing is changing with time. There is energy flowing the series of plates, and the rate at which energy flows must be constant.

The thickness of the plates doesn't matter for conserving energy. The reason the plates need to be thin is so that the temperature at each plate is one temperature. If the plates were thick the temperature between the sides could be different.